Fantasy book(s) with magic powers gained from rose gold rings
So I don't have many memories from this book, and I've looked over the internet quite a few times before trying here.
The core information:

There's not a lot of magic holders in the story, and it's from rose gold rings.

The main character is quite young.

Close to the end, the main character is in an abandoned underground city that's futurist like.

I read this book in French, probably translated from English.



In roughly which year did you read this? And was the main character male or female?

This is The Fifth Ring by Mitchell Graham.

Despite a massive defeat decades ago, Karas Duren, Lord of Alor Sator,
is again attempting to conquer the neighbouring kingdoms and bring
them under one rule – his own. Now the evil ruler holds a weapon of
mass destruction: a single ring left over from the Ancients that will
allow him to control people and destroy everything and anyone who
chooses to oppose him – including his own brother.
In a small village, a young boy wins a ring in a fencing tournament.
Born and raised on a small farm, Mathew has little contact with the
outside world, until the day his father is murdered in front of his
eyes. Mat kills the murderer in revenge and must run for his life.
Joining him is a mysterious priest, a few friends, and his love, Lara.
During his flight Mathew discovers unusual powers in the ring, powers
that make him one of the most potent men on the planet – and bring him
to Duren's attention...A story of courage, love, and valour, this is
epic fantasy at its best.

This review for the second book in the series, The Emerald Cavern, mentions a cavernous underground city and the possession of 'rose gold rings' as the catalyst for magic.

Despite the best efforts of his enemies in The Fifth Ring, Mathew
appears to have landed on his feet, in the safest place possible.
Ensconced in Tenley Palace, under the fierce protection of King Gawl
-- a giant of a man and the ruler of Sennia -- what could possibly happen to Mathew, his beloved Lara, and the others? Nothing could be
as horrifying as the ghoulish Orlocks or as powerful as Karas Duren.
And, Mathew has his incredible ring to fight anyone who threatens the
fragile peace of the land.
But, who truly understands the "magic" of these astonishing rose-gold
rings? So little is known about the makers, the civilisation that
collapsed and vanished long before this new, agrarian society began to
reclaim the world. Wonders beyond comprehension may remain buried far
beneath them, suffocated in the detritus of their own incomprehensible
collapse. Where there is wonder though, there is horror, and no one
can say with certainty which aspects the rings represent.


Well you're Amazing, it's Indeed the one ! Thanks a lot !!!

@FelixHap - You're very welcome indeed.
